# XSLT how to loop through each node and wrap it in a tag

Tags: xml, xslt

Here is the XML:

```
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g>
        <text id="b376">
            <tspan x="59" y="156" font-size="13px" font-family="Arial">80</tspan>
        </text>
        <use xlink:href="#b376" fill="#000000"/>
        <text id="b374">
            <tspan x="59" y="204" font-size="13px" font-family="Arial">60</tspan>
        </text>
        <use xlink:href="#b374" fill="#000000"/>
        <defs>testDef</defs>
     </g>
</svg>
```

Here is my XSL input:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="g">
    <g>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="use|defs"/>
      <defs>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[name() != 'use' and name() != 'defs']"/>
      </defs>
    </g>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want to wrap all nodes in a defs tag EXCEPT use tags and defs tags.  So the 2 text nodes would be wrapped in defs tags but defs and use would not.

Here is what I am getting

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <g>
    <use xlink:href="#b376" fill="#000000"/>
    <use xlink:href="#b374" fill="#000000"/>
    <defs>testDef</defs>
    <defs>
      <text id="b376">
        <tspan x="59" y="156" font-size="13px" font-family="Arial">80</tspan>
      </text>
      <text id="b374">
        <tspan x="59" y="204" font-size="13px" font-family="Arial">60</tspan>
      </text>
    </defs>
  </g>
</svg>
```

This is what I want:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
      <g>
        <use xlink:href="#b376" fill="#000000"/>
        <use xlink:href="#b374" fill="#000000"/>
        <defs>testDef</defs>
        <defs>
          <text id="b376">
            <tspan x="59" y="156" font-size="13px" font-family="Arial">80</tspan>
          </text>
        </defs>
         <defs>
          <text id="b374">
            <tspan x="59" y="204" font-size="13px" font-family="Arial">60</tspan>
          </text>
        </defs>
      </g>
    </svg>
```

I am using [this](http://online-toolz.com/tools/xslt-transformation.php) online tool to test.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your current output, where all of the `<text>` elements are wrapped in a single `<defs>` tag, is exactly what I would expect from reading your XSL code -- for every `<g>`, you have a single `<defs>` *within which* you handle all of the elements that are not `<use>` or `<defs>`:

```
<xsl:template match="g">
    <g>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="use|defs"/>

        <!-- This part here: -->
        <defs>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[name() != 'use' and name() != 'defs']"/>
        </defs>

    </g>
</xsl:template>
```

Since `<xsl:apply-templates select="*[name() != 'use' and name() != 'defs']"/>` is *inside* the literal `<defs>`, **all** of the non-`use` and non-`refs` elements are processed as a batch, within that single literal `<defs>` element.

You apparently want each non-`use` and non-`defs` element wrapped in its own `<defs>`.  In this case, you need to move the literal `<defs>` to *within* a separate template that matches on non-`use` and non-`defs` elements.

A quick-and-dirty refactoring might look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- Identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- We don't really need a specific template for <g>, so 
        we let the identity template handle that case. -->

    <!-- The only case where we need to define a different flow is
        for children of <g> elements, that aren't <use> or <defs>. -->
    <xsl:template match="*[name(..) = 'g'][name() != 'use' and name() != 'defs']">
        <!-- The template matches _each_ such element, so if we
            put the literal `<defs>` here, we get that `<defs>` as
            a wrapper for _each_ such element.  -->
        <defs>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </defs>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this approach also leaves the original `<use>` and `<defs>` elements in the same location within the `<g>` parent.

Comment: The `[name(..) = 'g']` predicate is a little weird.  A location path starting with `g/*` would be simpler and more natural.  Also, instead of the `[name() != ...]` predicate, I'd consider *no* predicate, and instead overriding with a template matching `g/use|g/defs`.

Comment: And you've used `xsl:copy-of` where you appear to mean `xsl:copy` containing `xsl:apply-templates`.

Comment: I do not agree that `[name(..) = 'g']` predicate is weird.
On the contrary, it reads in a quite natural way:
*The name of the parent element is 'g'*.
Another possibility is `[parent::g and ...]` - all within **one** predicate.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, the use of `xsl:copy-of` was quite deliberate.  My understanding is that `xsl:copy-of` is a single operation, whereas `xsl:copy` containing `xsl:apply-templates` recurses down the entire descendants tree, and could thus be expensive.  In this particular case, the context element simply needs to be wrapped in `<defs>` tags.  There's no need to process the descendants separately, so `xsl:copy-of` seems to make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Your expected output shows that the order of element
is important to you.

You want **first**  `use` and `defs` tags and only **after them**
all remaining elements, each wrapped in its own `defs`
element.

In order to achieve this use the following script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="g">
    <g>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="use|defs"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="*[name() != 'use' and name() != 'defs']">
        <defs>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
        </defs>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </g>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As you see, I added a `for-each` loop with the `select`
attribute copied from your example.

The content of this loop:

- creates wrapper `defs` element,
- and **inside it** "replays" the source element
  (the current element of the loop).